# Change Streams with Amazon DocumentDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I am setting up a microservice which needs to react on changes of a Amazon DocumentDB. When working with MongoDB I would use Reactive Change Streams for that. If I do this with the DocumentDB I get an exception when registering the change listener saying that the change streams are currently not supported.

```
2019-02-12T11:46:15.513+0100 E QUERY    [js] Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "The $changeStream stage is currently not supported",
    "code" : 303
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:18:14
_assertCommandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:534:17
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:618:16
DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:260:9
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1062:12
DBCollection.prototype.watch@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1589:12
@(shell):1:1
```

For the "old-style"-solution (op-log-tailing) I didn't find any hint on how to implement this.

What is the recommended setup to register to db changes on the Amazon DocumentDB?

Comment: Might work if you're using redis-oplog ?

Comment: Definitely worth a try. Do you have any experiences with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon DocumentDB now supports change streams: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/10/amazon-documentdb-with-mongodb-compatibility-adds-support-for-change-streams/

Answer (score 0):

I would use dynamodb. It is born for it